# How can I show the drop-down lists for countries/administrative areas (from Addressfield) as exposed filters in Views?

Tags: views, entities

When editing the values of addresses provided by the Addressfield module, selecting certain countries (e.g., the United States) automatically populates a drop-down list of states.

I would like to do the same thing in a View using exposed filters-- when a user selects a country using the exposed filter for country, it should make available a select box for administrative area (state/province).

Adding exposed filters for the country and administrative area do not generate drop-down lists; instead, I simply get a plain text field with the standard options- *is*, *contains*, etc.

By installing the [Countries](http://drupal.org/project/countries) module, I can get a drop-down list of the countries (but not the administrative areas).  How can I do this using only the Addressfield module?

Is there a pre-existing solution to make it work like it does on the edit page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, there is [no such views integration in the Addressfield module](http://drupal.org/node/991834), although the linked issue does include a discussion of possible directions to take to tackle the problem.